# Absolutely positioning <tr>'s in a complex structure

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a pretty complex UI control that I have to develop. The left halve is a TreeTable component, that consists of a `<table>` element. The right halve is a `SVG` component that displays data for each row of the left treeTable. Both sides need to be relatively independent per requirement but need to behave as one with synchronized scrolling et cetera.

Therefore, the overall structure looks like this

```
<div>
   <div id="leftComponent">
      <table>...</table
   </div>
   <div id="rightComponent">
      <svg>...</svg>
   </div>
</div>
```

I added performance optimizations for huge datasets with > 1m rows so that only the rows in the viewport on either side would be actually rendered and in DOM.

This leads to the following problems:

1. When I scroll on the right side, the elements are absolutely positioned and I can therefore use the native smooth scrolling. For example, halve of a row may be visible at the top of the viewport, then all the other rows, then another halve row at the bottom of the viewport. How do I offset the leftComponent table content in a way, so that the table's rows match the right sides rows again? Absolute positioning on the `<tr>`'s does not work. I also implementered rasterized scrolling so that the user could only scroll in multiples of a rowHeight, but that idea was quickly shot down. Offseting the whole `<table>` element with something like `<table style="margin-top:1337px">` does not really work either as the `<table>` header will not be sticky at the top then. Are there better ways?
2. As both sides are relatively standalone, each side has its own scrollbars. The y-axis scrollbar from the leftComponent is unwanted however as it disturbs the overall feeling of the UI. Simply setting it to `overflow-y: hidden` does not work as now I cannot scroll on the left side. My only idea for this is to catch the `WheelEvent` and create a `ScrollEvent` for the rightComponent artifically from it. I also played around with `scrollbar-width: none;` in CSS but that disables both scrollbars. The x-axis scrollbar needs to stay both visually and functionally, just the y-axis scrollbar needs to go visually, but still remain intact functionally. I also tried hiding the y-axis scrollbar with `margin-right: -20px`, which does work, but seems extremely hacky to me.

To summarize:

1. Both sides are relatively independent and need to stay that way but need to behave "in sync"
2. There shouldn't be a y-axis scrollbar between both components visually but I still need to be able to scroll on the left component
3. I need to be able to also scroll / offset the left `<table>` part by an arbitrary amount of pixels to match the right side which can be scrolled freely.
4. A total rewrite of the left side and converting the `<table>` structure into a `<div>` structure that can then be absolutely positioned should be avoided if possible, as it would be a lot of work.
5. I still need to be able to apply my performance improvement for the leftComponent, so that only the X rows in the viewport are rendered, but at the correct y position to stay in sync with the right side.

Any good ideas on this one?

EDIT: As per request i added some screenshots.
[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

Explanation. In the first image, you can see everything scrolled up to the top. Both rows on each side do match perfectly. In the second picture you see what i mean by halve scrolled down rows. The top most row is only visible by a few pixels. Naturally i want this to look like in the first picture, both rows being aligned perfectly. However, as the left component only has a `<table>` element, i cannot position the `<tr>` elements down by a few pixels so that it matches the right side, once my performance optimization is active. Additionally, the scrollbar in the middle needs to go, as describd above, but x-axis scrolling still needs to be active in both the left and right component.

If you need more infos, ask me please.

Comment: Perhaps you can show a visual output of both the ***right*** or ***expected*** output and the ***wrong*** output so visual thinkers could get a better grasp of what you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just to be completely clear; is it absolutely imperative that each side have it's own scrollbars?  That seems a little pointless if they are supposed to be locked together.

Comment: Does [this help at all?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop)

Comment: @dalelandry I have added 2 screenshots and more explanation. I hope this helps. If you have any idea or more questions, ask me please.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Each side has to have its own x-axis scrollbars. Only the y-axis is locked and synchronized. No, the scrollTop does not help, as my performance optimization (this UI component needs to support 1m+ elements) makes sure only the parts in the viewport actually exist in DOM. This means only the <tr> elements within the viewport, exist in DOM. So the container around the table will have no real height and the <tr> elements are no positionable.

Comment: With a million rows, using partial row offsetting will be a bit meaningless. Because scrolling one pixel in the scroll bar will be equivalent to multiple rows.  It would only make sense for up to a few hunder rows.  So it might be a better user experience to snap to full rows anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure JS mockup using a `scrollTop` approach, as I suggested earlier, combined with relative positioning on the rows.

I think it is reasonably self explanatory.  Let me know if you have any questions.

```js
const leftComponent = document.getElementById("leftComponent");
const rightComponent = document.getElementById("rightComponent");
const svg = rightComponent.querySelector("svg");

const theadHeight = leftComponent.querySelector("thead").offsetHeight;
const tbodyRowHeight = leftComponent.querySelector("tbody tr").offsetHeight;

const numRows = 100;    // Number of rows in th table
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--table-height', (theadHeight + numRows * tbodyRowHeight) + 'px');


// Capture rightComponent scroll events
rightComponent.addEventListener('scroll', evt => {
  // Calculate top row index number based on scroll offset and row height
  const topRowIndex = Math.floor(rightComponent.scrollTop / tbodyRowHeight);
  // Work out how many pixels into the top row that the scroll position is
  const scrollFractionalAdjustment = - (rightComponent.scrollTop % tbodyRowHeight);
  // Set the position relative top value for the table rows.
  // This will adjust their vertical position on the page based on scroll fractional offset we just calculated.
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--scroll-fractional-adjustment', scrollFractionalAdjustment + 'px');
  // Update the table and graph based on out top row index
  populateTableRows(topRowIndex);
  populateGraph(topRowIndex);
});



function populateTableRows(topRowIndex)
{
  let n = topRowIndex;
  const rows = leftComponent.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
  rows.forEach((row, i) => {
    const cols = row.querySelectorAll("td");
    cols[0].textContent = "row" + n + " with very long text";
    cols[1].textContent = "row" + n;
    n++;
  });
}


function populateGraph(topRowIndex)
{
}


// Initial setup
populateTableRows(0);
populateGraph(0);
```

```css
:root {
  --scroll-fractional-adjustment: 0px;
  --table-height: 10000px;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
th, td {
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
th {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: white;
}

.system {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#leftComponent.
#rightComponent {
  height: var(--table-height);
}

#leftComponent {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll hidden;
}
#leftComponent tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#leftComponent tbody td {
  position: relative;
  top: var(--scroll-fractional-adjustment);
}
#leftComponent table th,
#leftComponent table td
{
  max-width: 150px;
}

#rightComponent {
  width: 70%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
#rightComponent .rightContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--table-height);
}
#rightComponent svg {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="system">
   <div id="leftComponent">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>ID Blub</th>
            <th>Foo</th>
            <th>Sort string</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>row0 with very long text</td>
            <td>row0</td>
            <td>Foo something</td>
            <td>r2u58</td>
          <tr>
            <td>row0 with very long text</td>
            <td>row0</td>
            <td>Foo something</td>
            <td>r2u58</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>row0 with very long text</td>
            <td>row0</td>
            <td>Foo something</td>
            <td>r2u58</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>row0 with very long text</td>
            <td>row0</td>
            <td>Foo something</td>
            <td>r2u58</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>row0 with very long text</td>
            <td>row0</td>
            <td>Foo something</td>
            <td>r2u58</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div id="rightComponent">
      <div class="rightContainer">
        <svg>
          <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```